# How to show multiline text with scrollbar on SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am looking for a way by which I can show some multiline text data on a SVG along with scrollbar.

I have tried the option of adding a textarea along with foreignObject which works with Chrome, FF, Opera but fails in IE.

```
d3.select("g")
    .append('foreignObject')
    .attr("class", "csFObject")
    .attr("x", mouse[0] + 160)
    .attr("y", mouse[1] + 10)
    .attr('width', 280)
    .attr('height', 290)
    .append("textarea")
    .attr("cols", 37)
    .attr("rows", 14)
    .attr("readonly", "true")
    .attr("style", "overflow:auto;font-size: 14px;background-color:#ededed;border: 0px; width:280px;")
    .attr("x", mouse[0] + 160)
    .attr("y", mouse[1] + 20)
    .attr("id", "txtAreaGeoDescription")
    .attr("class", "txtAreaGeoDescription");

var textarea;
{
    textarea = document.getElementById("txtAreaGeoDescription");
    textarea.value = geoDescription;
    //textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
}
```

So looking for other options,
Another way I tried is :

```
d3.select("g").append("g")
    .attr("width", 280)
    .attr("height", 290)
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .append("text")
        .attr("x", mouse[0] + 160)
        .attr("y", mouse[1] + 20)
    .call(wrap, 280,geoDescription);
```

Here I am able to get the data visible on all the browsers but I need a scroll bar to appear after 5 lines of data shown.

Any suggestion on how can I achieve to show a multiline data on a SVG with scrollbar.

Comment: http://www.carto.net/svg/gui/scrollbar/

Comment: Hi Robert, instead of image can we use text.
Do you have an example for it.

Comment: The link works with anything try it, if you get stuck post a question with the specifics.